# Why the producer with unlimited buffered channel doesn't return or return invalid data from channel?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Look at this adopted [example from official Kotlin documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#building-channel-producers):

```
package com.example

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.produce
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val producer = produce {
        for (x in 1..5) send(x)
    }

    for (i in producer) {
        println(i)
    }

    println("Done!")
}
```

If I run it will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Done!
```

As you can see here is using unbuffered channel by default. Let's change it to buffered channel:

```
package com.example

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.Channel
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.produce
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.runBlocking

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val producer = produce(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED) {
        for (x in 1..5) send(x)
    }

    for (i in producer) {
        println(i)
    }

    println("Done!")
}
```

If I run it several times it will print:

```
1
Done!
```

or

```
2
Done!
```

or just

```
Done!
```

I suppose that the producer will put data to the buffered channel and the `for` loop will read data from it until it can do it (i.e. it will read if data is exists in channel OR channel is not closed). Thus I think the `for` loop should read all data from buffered channel even it was closed. Am I right?

Can anybody explain me why buffered channel cause such strange behavior of producer? Is it bug?

P.S.

- kotlin-stdlib v.1.2.21 (it is last version today)
- kotlinx-coroutines-core v.0.22.2 (it is last version today)

Comment: Looks like it is a bug: [kotlinx.coroutines#256](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kotlin team has confirmed that this is a bug and [opened an issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/256) for it in response to this question.

The description of the issue mentions that it only appears with the `produce` builder and provides a workaround, basically the inlined code of that convenience construct:

```
val producer = Channel<Int>(1)
launch(coroutineContext) {
    for(i in 1..2) {
        producer.send(i)
        println("Sent: $i")
    }
    producer.close()
}
```